# Sorting an array by providing an array of pointers as arguments

Tags: c++

I wrote this code, but it is only giving me an address of something:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int* a,int* b) 
{
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void sort(int* p[],int n) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        if(*p[i]>*p[i+1])
        swap(p[i],p[i+1]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={8,6,5,4,3,7,1};
    int* p[7];

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        p[i]=&arr[i];
    }

    sort(p,7);

    /*i tried to change arr[1] to p[1] or *p[1] but same output*/
    cout<<arr[1]<<arr[2];
    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm lacking in concept somewhere. The complete question is this:

> Write the following function that indirectly sorts the floats pointed to by the first n pointers in the array p by rearranging the pointers: void sort(float* p[],int n)

Please help.

Comment: Do you know how to sort a simple `int[]` rather than a `float*[]` (without resorting to `std::sort`, which you would do in real code but which would defeat the purpose of the exercise)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way of doing what you want, there are many ways it can be done better but it looks like your new to c++ so I tried to make it as simple as possible.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//not needed, std::swap does the same job!
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    std::swap(a, b);
}

//using a pointer to the array is better!
void sort(int arr[], int n)
{
    //two loops are needed to sort the entire array!
    for (int x(0); x < n - 1; x++)
    {
        //optimize the loop by removing already sorted items from loop
        int sorted = n - x;
        for (int y(0); y < sorted - 1; ++y)
            if (arr[y] > arr[y + 1])
                std::swap(arr[y], arr[y + 1]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    //vector or std::array better option!
    int arr[] { 8,6,5,4,3,7,1 };

    //provide the array to sort(), no need to make stuff harder
    sort(arr, 7);

    //Show you that the sort worked!
    for (int ccc = 0; ccc < 7; ccc++)
        std::cout << arr[ccc] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    cout << "Index 5: " << arr[5] << "\nIndex 6: " << arr[6] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a very good tutorial on sorting arrays: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/64-sorting-an-array-using-selection-sort/

Answer (score 0):

First of your code has a buffer overflow, which means undefined behaviour and anything it does is therefore by definition correct. In `sort` the index `i` goes over all array positions from 0 to n-1. But then you access `i+1`, which is one element beyond the array. For me the code segfaults.

Correcting this the output is "54" and here is what happens.

The swap function swaps the values in `arr` instead of swapping the pointers in `p`. The exercise asks you to indirectly sort the array, menaing the pointers. You need to use ** or *& there. So what happens in the sort loop is that 8 and 6 are swapped, then 8 and 5 are swapped and 8 and 4 are swapped and so on. So your array then is {6,5,4,3,7,1,8}. Last you output arr[1] and [2], which is 5 and 4. Since you don't output a space between them you get "54".